# FETCHING JSON DATA FROM THINGSPEAK TO ANDROID APP

Tags: java, android, json, iot

I am a beginner in Android and i am trying to fetch  json data from Thingspeak to my android app.

This is my code:

```
package com.example.shaheer.thingspeak;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    public void fetchData() {
        String lightApi = 
        "https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/444149/fields/1.json?api_key=EE90JXIIKAEFUT7S&results=2";
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,lightApi, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    JSONArray feeds = response.getJSONArray("feeds");
                    for(int i=0; i<feeds.length();i++){
                        JSONObject jo = feeds.getJSONObject(i);
                        String l=jo.getString("field1");
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,l,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                         }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To cut my story short,i am getting this following error:
**Error:(38, 10) error: ')' expected.**
Every brackets seems to be alright.Thanks for your help!!

Edit:This is my Logcat:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONBY7.png)

Comment: Why are you shouting?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
 public void fetchData(){
    String lightApi = "https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/444149/fields/1.json?api_key=EE90JXIIKAEFUT7S&results=2";
    JsonObjectRequest objectRequest =new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, lightApi, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        JSONArray feeds = response.getJSONArray("feeds");
                        for(int i=0; i<feeds.length();i++){
                            JSONObject jo = feeds.getJSONObject(i);
                            String l=jo.getString("field1");
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),l,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Merely saying "Use this code" is not a proper answer, even if it turns out to work.  You should invest at least a few words in explaining what your version does that corrects an issue in the code proposed by the question.  Otherwise you force people to do an "eyeball diff" to figure out what your actual recommendation is, and that's just inefficient.